# No choice for beveling edges

Tags: bevel

Say I've got a thin plate, like a cylinder, that's only 1mm thick - i.e. a disc. I want to bevel the edge all the way around.

Whenever I use the bevel tool, it puts the initial slice proportional to the depth of the surfaces. So, the "plate" surface that's get 90% of the bevel while the "edges" that are only .1mm wide get only 10% (making an angle of about 80deg).

I want the same bevel on both surfaces - i.e. the initial cut is at 45deg, not 80 ,so that he bevel is a smooth arc of constant curvature.

It doesn't seem to matter how I play with the popup setting: width or profile, it always stays at that 90/10 ratio.

Alternately, is there a simpler way of just rounding thin "edges"? (My actual shape is more complex than just a cylinder, so any solutions can't be **too** generic. As long as I can select the edges or faces I want to bevel, and by how much.)

[image]

Comment: This looks like the result of non-uniform scale. Select the object in object mode, press Ctrl+A and select scale. Then try your bevel again.

Comment: Well, that worked although I don't understand it. What is Ctrl-A doing, and how am I setting scale?

Comment: The long and the short of it is that when you scale things in object mode, it messes up blender's sense of it's "dimensions", which is known as having a non-uniform scale. Because of this, it's better to perform most operations in edit mode because a non-uniform scale will cause problems with bevels, insets, texture coordinates, etc... However, if you do end up making transforms in object mode, you can "re-acquaint" blender with it's dimensions by applying location, rotation, scale, etc.... The real answer is much more complicated, but this is just what I can fit in a comment.

Comment: Oh, I see. it sort of resets the baseline of the scaling and rotation. Thanks.